# How to use an existing table with in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel

I am extremely new to Laravel (like 2 days in learning it) and I've worked my through most of the Intro to Laravel laracast.

I thought today i'd give a my own project a go.

I want to be able to use an existing table in Laravel.  For instance, I have a bible table called 'kjv'.  It has the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `kjv` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `book` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `chapter` smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `verse` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contents` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `in-red` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `all-red` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And i've imported that into my laravel database.

The thing is, I dont want to create a new migration, as that would overwrite the data.

I want to be able to use the data in my project, so how would I go about this? I'm guessing I need a model, but I have no idea what i'd write in there.  Do I need a controller also?

I'd like to be able to start with a 'get verse' function in the model, so lets say, something along the lines of:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use App\KJV;

class KJV extends Model
{
    //

    public function verse($id) {

        $verse = KJV::find($id);

        return view("verse");

    }

}
```

Of course, I'm really guessing here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Specify the table name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) in the `KJV` model:

```
protected $table = 'kjv';
```

Then this code will work:

```
KJV::find($id);
```

Comment: This is the best solution, make use of those optional variables that can be used, no need to complicate it further. After all, it is meant to be *Eloquent*.

Answer (score 1):

After you have your database set, either with `migrations` or just `importing` the database structure, you then create model which will contain all the `attributes` and `relationships` that you have. To use `CRUD` functionalities I suggest you use [`Resource Controllers`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers), after that you need to create a connection between a router and that resource controller, which you can find on that link just below the header